# Error in dynamically parametrizing fixtures in pytest

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I am running the code mentioned in the docs for dynamically generating parameters for fixture by using hook `pytest_generate_tests` the code is as follows

```
def test_valid_string(stringinput):
    assert stringinput.isalpha()

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--stringinput", action="append", default=[],
        help="list of stringinputs to pass to test functions")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'stringinput' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("stringinput",
                             metafunc.config.getoption('stringinput'))
```

on executing the above script , I am getting the following error 
[image]

Comment: Because your access for the option is wrong? `metafunc.config.getoption('--stringinput')` will fix the error.

Comment: This is isn't solving the problem, it says : " ValueError: no option named '--stringinput' "

Comment: Oh yes, you have to move the `pytest_addoption` hook to `conftest.py`, this should help. In general, avoid declaring hooks in test files to avoid hooks being executed too late. Btw it wasn't me who downvoted - in fact, I've upvoted the question so it's back to zero.

Comment: Thanks @hoefling , it did work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section by @hoefling, writing the hook in the `conftest.py` , solves the problem.